# I'm hosting a LAN party and could use some help mitigating power concerns

Tags: power, circuit-analysis

As mentioned, I'm hosting a LAN party for ~10 people in a few months. I've layed out a rough idea of what gear we'll have, where it will go, etc. However, I'm wondering if so many devices (TV, Xbox, Laptops, Monitors) will be too much.

Below is a diagram of my expectations as far as each piece of equipment that will require power. Additionally, I've included all outlets. The numbers beside them indicate which circuit they're on.

Can anyone let me know if this is safe and/or practical? I apologize if I haven't included enough information; I'm quite out of my element, but will do my best to edit this question and provide any missing detail.

[image: Diagram]

Circuits are 15A each, 120V outlets.

After some research, the numbers below are what I *believe* to be correct. Perhaps someone can acknowledge that they're "realistic", as I've gone off of what I could find online, but am not entirely certain how to apply the information I've gathered.

```
Laptops:         11  x   80W  =  880W
Monitors:         7  x   90W  =  630W
Televisions:      3  x  170W  =  510W
Xboxes:           3  x  110W  =  330W
Network Switches: 2  x    5W  =   10W
                                 ----
                                2360W (?)
```

Comment: Your question is missing power requirement of each device, the rating of the outlets (both available on the device labels) and your supply voltage / location.

Comment: Ack - thanks! Let me get some answers to those questions! Perhaps you can help me narrow down what's relevant of this information I pulled off the circuit breaker: These switches say `15SWD` on them. While most of the circuits say `10ka 120v-240v`, these two circuits (and a couple others) have a `TEST` button instead. I'm in the USA. (I'll see if I can find the approx power req for each device now!)

Comment: +1 for considering the possible pitfalls and working to find a solution.

Comment: If you are in the USA, your outlets will be 120 V, and each circuit is fed from a 15 Amp breaker.  You should limit the load on each circuit to about 1500 watts.  It looks like you have two circuits available, so you will be limited to 3000 Watts total.

Comment: @PeterBennett Thank you. I've done some research and found what I *think* are the correct numbers for each device, thus determining total watts. However I'm fearful that I may be misunderstanding or converting improperly; do the wattages I've shared seem "realistic"? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing with the comment of Peter Bennett. He's correct in stating to limit the load on each circuit to around 1500W to not trip the breaker.

Using the layout I came to this possible power layout:

1. Circuit 1

   - laptop 1 -> 6, 9: 560W
   - monitor 1 -> 7: 630W
   - switch 1 -> 2: 10W
     Total power consumption: 1180W

Divide the laptops and monitors equally over the 2 outlets. When using distribution plugs, fill first all the available plugs in the distribution plug connected to the wall outlet with more distribution plugs. (To avoid 1 long cable with all the plugs in series.)

2. Circuit 2:

   - laptop 7, 8, 10, 11: 320W
   - tv 1 -> 3: 510W
   - xbox 1 -> 3: 330W
     Total power consumption: 1160W

Feel free to move around a bit if you have problems with available cable lengths. Just don't go over the limit.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm also realizing now that the wattages I supplied are (I believe) at full load, though we don't plan on having all devices running simultaneously at any point. I'm happy that we're still under the 80% mark even at our worst. I'll use this distribution for sure!

Comment: @Santi That's good you supplied them at full load. Better be safe (and have a good margin) than sorry. Have fun with the event!